# Custom layout manager for posts

Tags: posts, wp-query, screen-layout

I have created a 'custom layout manager' for front page posts for my client, because he wants control over how his posts look.

[image]

I've set up the backend - I have layout saved in an array, for each 'custom' block - gallery, poll or image, I can select what post to show there, and it all works (it's not perfect, but since I need to have this functioning ASAP this will do). I can arrange these blocks as I want to and put new ones in, and remove the ones I don't need.

Now, what I need guidance for is how to actually display these posts.

First thing that came to mind is to create a HTML that I'd just place inside the loop and output the posts, something like:

```
$posts3_right = '<div class="post_container posts3_right">
                    <div class="left">
                        <div class="article">
                            <a href="'. esc_url(get_permalink()) .'" class="article_image" style="background: #00B588; '. (isset($image_out) && $image_out != '') ? 'background-image:url('. esc_url($image_out) .');' : '' .' background-size: cover; background-position: center center;">
                            </a>
                            <div class="article_content">
                                <a href="'. esc_url(get_permalink()) .'" class="post_title">'. wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 10) .'</a>
                                <div class="excerpt">'. get_the_excerpt() .'</div>
                                <div class="comment_cat_container">
                                    <a title="Kommentera" href="'. comments_link() .'" class="comment_count">'. get_comments_number() .'</a>
                                    '. $category_out .'
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <div class="article">
                            <a href="'. esc_url(get_permalink()) .'" class="article_image" style="background: #00B588; '. (isset($image_out) && $image_out != '') ? 'background-image:url('. esc_url($image_out) .');' : '' .' background-size: cover; background-position: center center;">
                            </a>
                            <div class="article_content">
                                <a href="'. esc_url(get_permalink()) .'" class="post_title">'. wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 10) .'</a>
                                <div class="excerpt">'. get_the_excerpt() .'</div>
                                <div class="comment_cat_container">
                                    <a title="Kommentera" href="'. comments_link() .'" class="comment_count">'. get_comments_number() .'</a>
                                    '. $category_out .'
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="article">
                            <a href="'. esc_url(get_permalink()) .'" class="article_image" style="background: #00B588; '. (isset($image_out) && $image_out != '') ? 'background-image:url('. esc_url($image_out) .');' : '' .' background-size: cover; background-position: center center;">
                            </a>
                            <div class="article_content">
                                <a href="'. esc_url(get_permalink()) .'" class="post_title">'. wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 10) .'</a>
                                <div class="excerpt">'. get_the_excerpt() .'</div>
                                <div class="comment_cat_container">
                                    <a title="Kommentera" href="'. comments_link() .'" class="comment_count">'. get_comments_number() .'</a>
                                    '. $category_out .'
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>';
```

And so for other layouts, and I'd just stack them according to my layout array inside the loop.

But, nobody is guaranteeing me that sixth (in this case) post will be a poll one.

So this method kinda falls through the window. The other option I can think of is that I have `WP_Query()` with every section, and to somehow look after the offset posts that I need to show, so that after the 'custom layouts' I'd have chronologically ordered posts:

```
1    2
     3
4    5
 poll
6
7    8
9   10
```

But, the problem is that this will put additional queries on my front page. In this case I have 5 `WP_Queries` and each has it's own queries to the base (fetching the category, images etc.).

I'm afraid that this will be too much for the site.

Is there any way to do this without overloading the site with queries? I wouldn't want to have a super high CPU load on server, and possible crashes.

I know that there is `pre_get_posts` hook with which I could kinda set up my query. Could I use it with the first approach?

Comment: You could save the creation of this page as a `transient`, or cache the data on the hosting side.

Comment: I think I'll definitely put W3 Total Cache on the site, but I'm still worrying about it being too much.

Comment: If you are that worried you should look at a hosting solution that provides the solution of front side caching. Without knowing how to do it, it is worth the money for someone else to handle it,